# App Store is stuck downloading Software Update

Tags: applications, macos, mac-appstore, software-update

So, I have tried a lot of stuff but my App Store keeps getting stuck downloading the OS update that you see in the first picture below.

[image: App Store Screenshot]

I have tried canceling, restarting, deleting some files Library/Updates folder, also deleting some files in open $TMPDIR../C

The last thing I tried was doing what is suggested in this question [Mac App Store update stuck (Installing - Calculating...)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82551/mac-app-store-update-stuck-installing-calculating)

I am getting desperate because no matter what I do, when I try again, the update hangs at 125mb and the waiting time keeps going up when I wait.

[image]

What are my options at this point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest might be to just bypass the App Store altogether & get the update manually - this will only work if you are already on El Capitan, any version, which the App Store picture would indicate you are.

Just fetch the [10.11.4 Combo Updater](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1869) directly from Apple. This will bypass the App Store's delta updater, & also likely clean up whatever is causing the issue in the first place, by re-applying all updates since 10.11.0

Comment: Will try and get back to you

Comment: you were right. Thank you. I did not even know that tool existed